# Solving fully nonlinear 1st order.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

The problem is  the following:

Consider the PDE $c^2(u_x{^2}+u_y{^2}+u_z{^2})=1,c$ is a constant, which arises in geometrical optic. Suppose that on the sphere of radius $r$,$u=u^0=\alpha$ is a constant.
Determine u.

What's method do i solve ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We search solution  $u=f(x^2+y^2+z^2)$. Then we get two solutions:
$$u=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}{c}-\frac{r}{c}+\alpha$$
and
$$u=-\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}{c}+\frac{r}{c}+\alpha$$